# How to pyqtgraph legend action grouping?

Tags: pyqtgraph

I run legend items in groups in pyqtgraph. Is this possible?
Can I toggle multiple plots by clicking on a legend in pyqtgraph?

Answer (score 0):

PyQtGraph does not support grouping of items at present in the legend; it does support hiding individual plots by clicking on them.